# Call FREFunction with array of strings

Tags: java, actionscript, air-native-extension

Is it possible to call an external method:

```
this.extContext.call("GenerateProductsFunction", productList);
```

And retrieve the array of strings?:

```
public class GenerateProductsFunction implements FREFunction{
    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {

        args[0] // Get as Array?

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send back an array, the args[0] type will be FREArray, which is a subclass of FREObject.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS982b6f491d178e6d6565d9b1132a79a012f-7ff8.html

Comment: Through trial and error I found that out for myself. Thanks for the response though.